# Reducing Size of Android Application with audio files

Tags: android, performance

I have an android application where there are quite a number of audio files(.mp3 format) in the raw folder of resources.But the problem it creates is that the size of my app has become very large. What are the ways which I can use to reduce the size of app. Can't I compress that folder or use other technique ?

Comment: what format are the audio files in?

Answer (score 0):

you can minimize the size of mp3 by changing its sample rate and frequency so it will reduce its size almost 70 to 80 % but still its sound quality is good to hear

you can get mp3 compression or mp3 size reducer open source software on google
[click here for software compatible with window](http://mp3-compressor.en.softonic.com/)
once you reduce your size of mp3 automatically size of your app will get reduce

also delete the all unnecessary images ,stuff,xml ,java file from application so its size will definately get reduce

Answer (score -1):

The only options I see are:

- increase the compression of your mp3's
- load the mp3's from a different source ( via APK Expansion Files or from webserver )

Comment: does it help if the format of audio files can be changed ? If reducing size is the priority which format can be used?

Comment: format change is also possible ( e.g. ogg is very good for android ) but you can also do better compressions with mp3 - this is always a trade of between qualty and size